# eslint-plugin-import how to add flow declared modules to exceptions

Tags: eslint, flowtype, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a file in flow-typed directory with some common type declarations like:

**common-types.js**

```
// @flow

declare module 'common-types' {
  declare export type RequestState = {
    setLoading: () => void,
    setFinished: () => void,
    setError: (error: AxiosFailure) => void,
    reset: () => void,
    status: LoadingStatus,
    error: AxiosFailure | void,
  };

  declare export type LoadingStatus = '' | 'loading' | 'finished';

  declare export type ErrorObject = { [key: string]: string | string[] | Error };

  declare export type AxiosFailure = {
    status: number,
    data: ErrorObject,
  }

}
```

Now I import it like this in files:

```
import type { RequestState } from 'common-types';
```

but I get eslint-plugin-import errors about *missing file extension* as well as *unable to resolve path to module 'common-types'*

How do I deal with it?

Comment: Is `common-types` actually an npm module? Seems like it would be easier to make it a local file, then do `./common-types` if you're not actually declaring types of a real npm module.

Comment: it's not a module. I wanted to avoid making long imports like `../../../../../common-types`. If I make webpack alias then again flow is showing errors about module not found.

Comment: Usually if you're having to do that, it's an indication that your file structure isn't well-factored. Your types should just pass your code along with your data, so if your exporting a function that returns a type, re-export the type from that module too. If you import a function that returns a type, chances are you can import the type from that same module.

Comment: Problem arises when I use webpack aliases. In order to make flow not raise error when I import components from `commons` I have to ignore it in flow-typed by `declare module 'common' {
  declare module .exports: any;
}
`
but then if I tried to export types from there, I wouldn't get errors about exporting types that don't exist, because it's ignored.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks for your suggestions. After almost giving up I tried another approach and it works now.

Comment: I personally think rewriting paths with aliases is a code smell, but at the end of the day it is your call.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. As @logansmyth suggested in comment

> Your types should just pass your code along with your data

The problem I had was with webpack aliases. Flow pointed me errors about modules not being installed. Hovewer I [found out](https://github.com/trayio/babel-plugin-webpack-alias/issues/49) that I can use mappers in .flowconfig like:

```
module.name_mapper='^common' ->'<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/common'
```

along with webpack aliases, which makes eslint-plugin-import and flow happy as well properly type-checking. Now I import types along with `common` components, no messing with flow-typed directory.

Comment: It would be great if you could show a bit more of the config code, I'm not totally able to follow what you ended up doing.

Comment: @fraxture refer to this GitHub issue https://github.com/trayio/babel-plugin-webpack-alias/issues/49. That's where I got the solution from.